Movie with Saladin encountered as a traveller on the road
Trying to recall a movie about the Crusades, or the time of the Crusades, where the hero encounters Saladin "on the trail," so to speak, early in the movie. 
As I recall, a big deal was not made of Saladin being anyone other than another traveller on the road - medieval history buffs, however, would have immediately made the connection.  
As I recall, Saladin was not a major character in this film but did appear later on.  His almost cameo-like appearance in the movie added to its appeal.
I remember it was an action film and I saw it on Amazon Prime.

Saladin was briefly in Hollywood action film 'Kingdom of Heaven'

Yes, but the description J Tibbs gave sounds nothing like Saladin's actions from Kingdom of Heaven. Saladin was very pivotal and emphasized in the context of the story.

Was my answer correct? If so, you should mark it as answered.

It sounds like Arn: The Knight Templar, a Swedish miniseries that is available on Amazon Prime.
In the plot, Arn Magnusson pursues a band of thieves, which leads him to Saladin, who is cornered and in peril. Arn saves Saladin's life, prompting the Sultan to thank him and caution him against moving towards Jerusalem, which is his army's target.

Sounds like it. I didn't know it was cut into a miniseries, I know of just two movies (who were edited into one in some editions).

Yep, Arn was re-cut into a single film for its English release!
